# How can I hide rows in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I've got this code to hide certain rows:

```
private static readonly Double DISPLAYED_HIDDEN_CUTOFF_VAL = 0.01;
private bool _hide;
. . .
_hide = racda.TotalItemPercentageOfItem < DISPLAYED_HIDDEN_CUTOFF_VAL;
if (_hide) 
{
    var hiddenRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[_curDescriptionTopRow, ITEMDESC_COL], _xlSheet.Cells[_curDescriptionTopRow, TOTALS_COL]];
    hiddenRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
}
```

The code is reached when it should be, but it has no effect: those rows are still visible. I want them to be on the spreadsheet, but not visible by default.

How can I accomplish that?

### UPDATE

This also did not work:

```
hiddenRange.Rows.Hidden = true;
```

...and this, in fact, caused the app to crash:

```
hiddenRange.Hidden = true;
```

### UPDATE 2

Even these rather sneaky ways of trying to accomplish it did nothing:

```
//hiddenRange.RowHeight = 0; <= did nothing
hiddenRange.Rows.RowHeight = 0; // <= also does nothing
```

### UPDATE 3

Yes, you're right, MacroMarc (replying to your comment below); this test code does work:

```
var testRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[2, 1], _xlSheet.Cells[2, 4]];
testRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
```

...so there's something discombobulated in my brain with regards to my code. Maybe it's a timing issue; I'll go over it again, with a fine-toothed comb.

Dicho discombobulatory code is:

```
    foreach (RawAndCalcdDataAmalgamated racda in 
_rawAndCalcdDataAmalgamatedList)
    {
        _hide = racda.TotalItemPercentageOfItem < 
DISPLAYED_HIDDEN_CUTOFF_VAL;
        AddDescription(racda.ItemDescription);
        AddDataLabels();

        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth1, racda.PurchasesMonth1,
racda.AvgPriceMonth1,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth1, MONTH1_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth2, racda.PurchasesMonth2, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth2,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth2, MONTH2_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth3, racda.PurchasesMonth3, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth3,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth3, MONTH3_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth4, racda.PurchasesMonth4, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth4,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth4, MONTH4_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth5, racda.PurchasesMonth5, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth5,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth5, MONTH5_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth6, racda.PurchasesMonth6, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth6,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth6, MONTH6_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth7, racda.PurchasesMonth7, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth7,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth7, MONTH7_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth8, racda.PurchasesMonth8, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth8,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth8, MONTH8_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth9, racda.PurchasesMonth9, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth9,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth9, MONTH9_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth10, racda.PurchasesMonth10, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth10,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth10, MONTH10_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth11, racda.PurchasesMonth11, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth11,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth11, MONTH11_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth12, racda.PurchasesMonth12, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth12,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth12, MONTH12_COL);
        AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth13, racda.PurchasesMonth13, 
racda.AvgPriceMonth13,
            racda.PercentOfTotalMonth13, MONTH13_COL);

        AddTotalsColData(racda.TotalItemPackages, 
racda.TotalItemPurchases, racda.TotalItemAvgPrice,
            racda.TotalItemPercentageOfItem);

        if (_hide)
        {
            var hiddenRange = 
_xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[_curDescriptionTopRow, ITEMDESC_COL], 
_xlSheet.Cells[_curDescriptionTopRow, TOTALS_COL]];
            hiddenRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
        }
        _lastRowAdded = _curDescriptionTopRow + 3;
        AddBottomBorder(_lastRowAdded);
        _curDescriptionTopRow = _curDescriptionTopRow + 4;
    }
```

...or, stripped of extraneous details:

```
        foreach (RawAndCalcdDataAmalgamated racda in 
_rawAndCalcdDataAmalgamatedList)
        {
            _hide = racda.TotalItemPercentageOfItem < DISPLAYED_HIDDEN_CUTOFF_VAL;

            AddMonthData(racda.PackagesMonth1, racda.PurchasesMonth1, racda.AvgPriceMonth1,
                racda.PercentOfTotalMonth1, MONTH1_COL);
            . . .

            if (_hide)
            {
                var hiddenRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[_curDescriptionTopRow, ITEMDESC_COL], _xlSheet.Cells[_curDescriptionTopRow, TOTALS_COL]];
                hiddenRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
            }
            _lastRowAdded = _curDescriptionTopRow + 3;
            _curDescriptionTopRow = _curDescriptionTopRow + 4;
        }
```

### UPDATE 4

It's working now; I had to change the row range from a single one to multiple:

```
if (_hide)
{
    var hiddenRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[_curDescriptionTopRow, ITEMDESC_COL], _xlSheet.Cells[_lastRowAdded, TOTALS_COL]];
    hiddenRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
}
```

...perhaps it was working *as coded* before, I just didn't notice it, because what I coded (hiding only one row of every four below the threshold value) was not what I was intending (hiding all four rows below the threshold).

Now the problem is that they (certain rows) are hidden, but I'm not seeing how the user can make those rows visible (which is how the legacy hand-crafted spreadsheet works).

I found out how to do that (manually unhide) [here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Show-or-hide-columns-and-rows-659c2cad-802e-44ee-a614-dde8443579f8#bmdisplayrowcolumn). I don't really need to do that myself, I just need to know the user can do it.

Comment: Original code should work. have you double checked the variables in the range etc? If you hard code in some row/column values does it work?

Comment: Okay, czech out Update 3.

Comment: So i guess you need to find out what is happening to the variables that determine the row and column numbers: `_curDescriptionTopRow`, `ITEMDESC_COL` etc

Comment: I got it now; you headed me down the right direction. It actually is hiding one row now, but I don't want just one row to be hid; I want four each time (they are all related).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it to work, first in a specific way:

```
private static readonly Double DISPLAYED_HIDDEN_CUTOFF_VAL = 0.01;
private bool _hide;
private Worksheet _xlSheet;
. . .
_hide = racda.TotalItemPercentageOfItem < DISPLAYED_HIDDEN_CUTOFF_VAL;
. . .
if (_hide)
{
    var hiddenRange = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[_curDescriptionTopRow, ITEMDESC_COL], _xlSheet.Cells[_lastRowAdded, TOTALS_COL]];
    hiddenRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
}
```

...now in a more general/abstract way:

```
if ([some condition where you want rows to be hidden])
{
    var hiddenRange = yourWorksheet.Range[yourWorksheet.Cells[firstRowToHide, firstColToHide], yourWorksheet.Cells[lastRowToHide, lastColToHide]];
    hiddenRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using other libraries, ClosedXML is fantastic when working with Excel and free to use.

https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Here is an example of how to hide rows in a worksheet:

```
 var wb = new XLWorkbook();
 var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Hide Unhide");
 ws.Columns(1, 3).Hide();
 ws.Rows(1, 3).Hide();
 ws.Column(2).Unhide();
 ws.Row(2).Unhide();
 wb.SaveAs("HideUnhide.xlsx");
```

Source: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Hide%20Unhide%20Row%28s%29%2fColumn%28s%29&referringTitle=Documentation

Would strongly recommend it, it provides lots of useful and nice naming conventions for several functions. Hope that's of some help!

Comment: I will look into this for my next project, but I'm almost finished with the current one and don't want to change all my existing code. Thanks for the tip, though!